# Validate Alphabetic Characters in a Cell

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula

I am trying to validate ID's that follow specific conditions. These are:

- 10 character length
- 1st character = numerical
- 2nd character = alphabetical
- 3rd-8th character = numerical
- 9th character = "/"
- 10th character = alphabetical

e.g. 1A234567/B

I am have no problem with most of the formula, but I am stuck how to validate the alphabetic characters at character 2 & 10.

My current formula (excluding the formulas for the alphabetic characters):

```
=IF(AND(LEN(F2)=10,ISNUMBER(--MID(F2,3,6)),MID(F2,9,1)="/"),"Valid","Invalid")
```

I hope someone can help ! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, IMHO fun, way to do this is through `FILTERXML()`. Yes, it's probably more verbose than nested `AND()` statements, but you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=NOT(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&A1&"</s></t>","//s[string-length()=10][concat(substring(.,1,1), substring(., 3,6))*0=0][translate(concat(substring(., 2, 1), substring(., 10)), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')=''][substring(.,9,1)='/']")))
```

- `[string-length()=10]` - Test if total length equals 10;
- `[concat(substring(.,1,1), substring(., 3,6))*0=0]` - Test if when we concatenate the 1st character with the 3-8th character equals 0 when multiplied by 0. Meaning: we validate that these characters are numeric;
- `[translate(concat(substring(., 2, 1), substring(., 10)), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','')='']` - Validate that when we translate all uppercase characters to nothing in the concatenated string from the 2nd and last character equals an empty string;
- `[substring(.,9,1)='/']` - Validate that the 9th character equals a forward slash.

---

**Note**:

- `WAAR` is Dutch for `TRUE`;
- You can use this in cell-validation when you would apply a rule;
- `FILTERXML()` is case-sensitive;
- More on `FILTERXML()` and the usage of it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194).

Comment: Thank you. Not something I have used before but works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Just an excuse for me to try out the shiny new [Advanced Formula Environment](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/advanced-formula-environment-a-microsoft-garage-project/)

You can create more extensive lambdas like this:

```
=LAMBDA(cell, lower, upper,
    LET(
        length, LEN(lower),
        seq, SEQUENCE(1, length),
        splitCell, MID(cell, seq, 1),
        splitLower, MID(lower, seq, 1),
        splitUpper, MID(upper, seq, 1),
        AND(
            SUM(
                (splitCell >= splitLower) *
                    (splitCell <= splitUpper)
            ) = length,
            LEN(cell) = length
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

*EDIT*

The formula above would be case insensitive. To make it cases sensitive, you could use CODE, but this would need to be wrapped in IFERROR:

```
=LAMBDA(cell, lower, upper,
    IFERROR(
        LET(
            length, LEN(lower),
            seq, SEQUENCE(1, length),
            splitCell, CODE(MID(cell, seq, 1)),
            splitLower, CODE(MID(lower, seq, 1)),
            splitUpper, CODE(MID(upper, seq, 1)),
            AND(
                SUM(
                    (splitCell >= splitLower) *
                        (splitCell <= splitUpper)
                ) = length,
                LEN(cell) = length
            )
        ),
        FALSE
    )
)
```